# Summernote buttons varying height

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, summernote

I have a Summernote WYSIWYG editor inside a Bootstrap modal. It uses a custom toolbar. (Although, this problem still occurs using the default toolbar).

As you can see in the image below, some of the buttons are varying in height. It's particularly noticeable with the dropdown next to the color change button.

[image: Varying height buttons]

Am I missing a file or definition that forces the buttons to be the same size?

Here are my included CSS files:

```
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../assets/js/docs.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../scripts/summernote.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#news_editor').summernote({height:150,toolbar:[
    ['style',['bold','italic','underline','clear']],
    ['fontface',['fontname']],
    ['textsize',['fontsize']],
    ['fontclr',['color']],
    ['alignment',['ul','ol','paragraph']],
    ['insert',['link','picture','table']],
    ['adv',['codeview']]
    ]});
});
...
```

And here is the entire HTML file: http://pastebin.com/G3Heae8J

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would you try to change the html5 doctype?

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Unfortunately it didn't fix another error I have which I hoped would get fixed at the same time.
The error which occurs is this: http://imgur.com/d44v2GX, but since you answered my question I will still mark you as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. For me, I had written a generic CSS rule affecting all `div`s, `span`s and `p`s, which caused some of the buttons which contain `spans` to be the wrong size.  So if the previous answer doesn't work for you, check your styles for offending rules.

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same issue. I'm not completely sure about the reason but I think it's got something to do with default bootstrap CSS which I compiled together with summernote CSS and other CSS used in my application.

The bottom of the issue is the line-height of the dropdown button is too big.

my solution is to override with a custom CSS like below to force the new line-height to fit the rest of the bottoms

> ```
> .note-toolbar .note-fontsize .note-btn-group button,
> .note-toolbar .note-para .note-btn-group button {
>     line-height: 12px !important;
> }
> ```

note I have only forced the .note-fontsize and .note-para groups because that's where the 'fontsize' button and 'paragraph' button resides in the category. for OP it'll be .note-textsize and .note-alignment